# Mapkit accessory button issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

im trying to get the index of the annotation when the disclosure button is tapped using the

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
  {

i have been pointed to the control.tag property, but whenever i use NSLog(@"tag value from control: %d", control.tag); it always returns 0.

anyone know how i can get the index of the annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tag (default) value is 0 unless you assign something else to it. Have you set another value to the tag property somewhere?

Comment: ok, think i was getting confused a little, i was reading that each annotation already had its own tag. thanks anyway